# Delete certain element from heap

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, heap

I know basic heap operations like insertion,deletion,finding minimum etc.I know deletion at certain index like deletion of element present at index 2 or so,but how to delete if we are to delete certain value that is present in the heap ?

In my opinion first we have to find the position of the certain element and than have to delete like we usually do.Pseudo code is welcome.

**My question is** :- How to delete certain valued element from heap and what will be the overall time complexity ?

Comment: Deleting is easy, but finding a specific element takes O(N) time.  If you need to be able to find and remove specific elements quickly, you should use a binary search tree or similar data structure

Comment: @amit  thanks for your response.It was really a weird question.Finding index in O(n) passed like flying colors.Thanks a lot and sorry I didn't know that it is a duplicate question :)

Comment: @MattTimmermans thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion :)